# How to get all nodes from "multi match" cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to make a cypher query to make nodes list which is using "multi match" as follows:

```
MATCH (N1:Node)-[r1:write]->(P1:Node),
      (P1:Node)-[r2:access]->(P2:Node)<-[r3:create]-(P1)
      WHERE r1.Time <r3.Time and r1.ID = r2.ID and r3.Time < r2.Time
      return nodes(*)
```

I expect the output of the Cypher to be all nodes of the result, but Cypher doesn't support nodes(*).

I know that there is a way to resolve this like thisa;

```
MATCH G1=(N1:Node)-[r1:write]->(P1:Node),
      G2=(P1:Node)-[r2:access]->(P2:Node)<-[r3:create]-(P1)
      WHERE r1.Time <r3.Time and r1.ID = r2.ID and r3.Time < r2.Time
      return nodes(G1), nodes(G2)
```

But the match part could be changed frequently so I want to know the way to get nodes from multi-match without handling variable for every match.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specific example is easy to consolidate into a single path, as in:

```
MATCH p=(:Node)-[r1:write]->(p1:Node)-[r2:access]->(:Node)<-[r3:create]-(p1)
WHERE r1.Time < r3.Time < r2.Time AND r1.ID = r2.ID
RETURN NODES(p)
```

*If you want the get distinct nodes, you can replace `RETURN NODES(p)` with `UNWIND NODES(p) AS n RETURN DISTINCT n`.*

But, in general, you might be able to use the [UNION](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/) clause to join the results of multiple disjoint statements, as in:

```
MATCH p=(:Node)-[r1:write]->(p1:Node)-[r2:access]->(:Node)<-[r3:create]-(p1)
WHERE r1.Time < r3.Time < r2.Time AND r1.ID = r2.ID
UNWIND NODES(p) AS n
RETURN n
UNION
MATCH p=(q0:Node)-[s1:create]->(q1:Node)-[s2:read]->(q0)
WHERE s2.Time > s1.Time AND s1.ID = s2.ID
UNWIND NODES(p) AS n
RETURN n
```

*The `UNION` clause would combine the 2 results (after removing duplicates). `UNION ALL` can be used instead to keep all the duplicate results. The drawback of using `UNION (ALL)` is that variables cannot be shared between the sub-statements.*